# Are all Snow Leopard apps resume-enabled when run in Lion?

Tags: macos, compatibility

I see this in iWork 08, is it the case for everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how each app is developed. It's a safe bet that Apple would implement this feature on most of the apps included in OS X as well as the iWork and iLife apps.

I would argue that another question just as important is which third-party apps have this feature. Not every third-party app that runs on Snow Leopard has Resume automatically when executed in Lion. This is a case-by-case situation, on which third-party app developers have to modify how their apps handle individual documents. Sometimes they have to make minor modifications, sometimes it may involve more complicated changes.

The same goes for all the other major document management features in Lion (such as Versions).

Hope this helps.

Comment: One of the questions that popped to my mind is that iWork 08 hasn't been updated for years yet it supports resume. What different thing that Apple did to iWork 08 that other cocoa apps doesn't do? (probably they're using a private API, but really? they can use it a few years before Lion even released?)

Comment: iWork 08 has been given minor updates since it came out. Technically, the ability to use the Lion features was not part of the original iWork 08, it was added as a minor update (via Software Update) the day Lion was released. I don't think they were "using" any of the Lion features before Lion, because such features were not even present in the pre-Lion Cocoa classes (like NSDocument).

Comment: Just to address your question more specifically: Apple did not do anything out of the ordinary. The way it usually works is that Apple has to release updates to OS X first, and then each app that might use new OS X features will be updated. But Software Update is supposedly smart enough to not send you app updates that your current OS X version cannot support.

Comment: But I'm quite positive that iWork 08 has not been updated when Lion was released (it wasn't even updated when they hand out the first Lion beta). They updated iWork 09 instead. So does that mean that any app that is written for snow leopard using NSDocument has resume enabled automatically without changing anything?

Comment: I've found the answer you're looking for. In the OS X Release Notes for Developers it is specified that Mac OS X 10.4 introduced auto-saving. However, this is NOT the same auto-saving that we get in Lion: Old auto-saving is the one that would store a copy of, say "Essay.doc", in the ~/Library/<YourApp> folder. Then, if there's a system crash, you would reopen the app to find a document titled "Essay.doc (autosaved)". This is what iWork 08 and 09 used to do. Here's the secret: If your app already did THAT old auto-saving, then it automatically got the NEW auto-saving when switching to Lion.

Comment: I forgot to mention: If your app did the old autosaving, then not only it gets the new autosaving, but it also gets the new Versions functionality as well. Pretty neat stuff--for us programmers, it shows the advantages of reusing your code and smart subclassing. Again, if your old Snow Leopard app did NOT have the old-autosaving, then the new auto-saving and Versions will not be there. Thus, my original answer still stands: It is on a case by case basis that we will see some apps already receiving the new features or not. It all goes back to whether or not they were using the old auto-saving.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, safari restores tabs/windows, Preview.app does the same with last viewed documents, Xcode 4.1 does that too.

I think all Apple apps support resume. Not sure what should be done for 3rd party applications to support this.

Comment: In here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1898/the-great-monkey I thought that without updating the apps it won't support Lion features. It seems like that's not quite the case for some apps, I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

All Cocoa apps (native Objective C apps for the Intel Architecture) support Resume

Comment: really? i have some intel apps that I know was written in cocoa but doesn't support resume

Comment: maybe theres exceptions, idk

Comment: This answer isn't exactly right or wrong, but it oversimplifies.  All Cocoa apps "support Resume" in the sense that there's no plist flag that developers have to explicitly set to turn on Resume (as there is for, say, Sudden Termination).  Then again, there are new API methods for it, so apps that haven't been updated for it might not behave correctly.  If a developer hasn't explicitly supported it, the defaults *might* be mostly good enough, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: You should edit my answer